# How to Fix : java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider

Tags: android

> I am playing an Audio file from a URL directly.
>   Here is the Code :

```
 try {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3");
                MediaPlayer player = new MediaPlayer();
                player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                player.setDataSource(getActivity(), uri);
                player.prepare();
                player.start();
            } catch(Exception e) {
                System.out.println(e.toString());
            }
```

> LogCat :
>
> W/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3: java.io.FileNotFoundException: No content provider: https://file-examples.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/file_example_MP3_700KB.mp3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the URL path is accessible from the browser directly.

change the order of api calls

```
 player.setDataSource(getActivity(), uri);
 player.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);           
 player.prepare();
```

try this.